# Сan't write the correct set of regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I'm using:

- Python 3.11.1
- Windows 10 pro
- requests 2.31.0
- beautifulsoup4 4.12.2
- pandas 2.1.2
- jupyter (writting in jup, but I'll make finish code in PyCharm)

I get the text via html request from the college website where they post the class schedule, I got them but in a scattered order as you can see in the image and text file (link below), and I can't write regular expressions to make the text readable, help me with this problem

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSNR-Gvp7MBcYQo0GM5nU3UC7DSIGMCwKq-eQGIY_alqORpe1pvZ00PI63wNuOyiJbZI_AP6nSeWWop/pubhtml'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html')

table = soup.find_all('table')[0]

world_titles = table.find_all('td')

world_table_titles = [title.text.strip() for title in world_titles]

# here I can't write reg exp to make text readable
clean_titles = [re.sub(r'[",\s]+', '', title) for title in world_table_titles]

print(clean_titles)
```

I would be so happy to get instructions on how to make a text readable by type:

```
ПОНЕДЕЛЬНИК

Время АСОИ-1-23
8:00
Физика (пр) Нарманбетова Г. Ж
9:30    Математика Алыкулова К.Б
11:00   Основы экономики, менеджмента и маркетинга Алтыбаева Ш.И.
12:40   Русский язык Омуркулова Г.М.
```

I know asking for a lot, but I'm really stuck

[text file](https://github.com/Jonyvershim/Project_Z)
[regular_expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tck09.png)

I was watching youtube tutorials, regex101, ai chat bots, but anything didn't help

Comment: [Please do not use links to or images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, reduce your problem to a set of examples that we can use to repeat your issue; [mre]

Comment: @MatBailie okay, I understood for future, I can't edit links now, need I delete and make new one more correct?

Comment: Why can't you [edit]? The link is right there next to "share", "follow", "close", etc. Generally don't delete and repost; instead, improve your post.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "make the text readable", anyway. Are you trying to extract some specific data out of the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/1206096).

Assuming you want to load a Google Sheet (from its `pubhtml` [url](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSNR-Gvp7MBcYQo0GM5nU3UC7DSIGMCwKq-eQGIY_alqORpe1pvZ00PI63wNuOyiJbZI_AP6nSeWWop/pubhtml)) to query specific data, maybe you should consider using [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) from [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) with a bit of *post-processing* ?

```
# read a brut version of the Google Sheeet html
from io import StringIO; import pandas as pd
tmp = (pd.read_html(StringIO(page.text))[0].iloc[4:, 1:]
           .dropna(how="all").T.set_index(4).T)

# to de-duplicate the headers (optional ?)
s = tmp.columns.to_series()
tmp.columns = (s.str.cat(s.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1)
                .astype(str), sep="-").where(s.duplicated(keep=False), s))

df = tmp.set_index(["Время-1", "Время-2"]).rename_axis(columns=None)
```

This makes a hierarchical dataframe and [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) will give you the expected output :

```
df.loc["ПОНЕДЕЛЬНИК", "АСОИ-1-23"]

Время-2
8:00                        Физика (пр) Нарманбетова Г. Ж.
9:30                              Математика Алыкулова К.Б
11:00    Основы экономики, менеджмента и маркетинга Алт...
12:40                         Русский язык Омуркулова Г.М.
Name: АСОИ-1-23, dtype: object
```

Output (*the whole table*):

```
print(df)

                          АСОИ-1-23 ауд.-1  ...      ЭУБДМ-1-23 ауд.-15
Время-1     Время-2                         ...                        
ПОНЕДЕЛЬНИК 8:00     Физика (пр)...    338  ...  Физика (пр)...     338
            9:30     Математика ...    407  ...  Математика ...     407
            11:00    Основы экон...    411  ...  Основы экон...     411
...                             ...    ...  ...             ...     ...
ПЯТНИЦА     9:30     Физика(лек)...    338  ...  Физика(лек)...     338
            11:00    Введение в ...    422  ...             NaN     NaN
            12:40    Кыргыз тил ...    405  ...  Кыргыз тил ...     405

[20 rows x 30 columns]
```

For fun, if you want to clone the formatting as well, you can use the [Styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html) :

```
def fmt_outeridx(ser):
    return ["""background-color: #00ffff; font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 14pt;text-align: center;""" for _ in ser]

def fmt_aya(ser):
    return np.where(ser.index.str.startswith("ауд"),
                    "background-color:#ffff99", "")

(
    df.style
        .set_properties(**{"font-weight": "bold",
            "border": "1px solid", "text-align": "center"})
        .apply_index(fmt_outeridx, axis=0, level=0)
        .apply_index(fmt_outeridx, axis=1)
        .apply(fmt_aya, axis=1)
)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, I really  ask for solve y problem 

Comment: You're welcome! I don't speak russian, so let me know if there is something wrong ;)

Comment: hello, you help me so much past time, I would be so thankfull if you have time for look to my new code issue :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77490140/how-get-schedule-with-io-with-aiogram-in-pycharm