# How get schedule with io with aiogram in pycharm

Tags: python, aiogram, stringio

I'm working on Get Schedule bot in telegram, I want that when the user selects the set schedule("установить расписание") function, the schedule of his classes automatically comes to him every morning at a given time, taking into account his group, of course. I used from io import StringIO to get the date and the site where the schedule is posted, but I can't bring it to mind so that the user can use it

like, Comtehno>>установить расписание(set schedule)>>ДПО-3-23 (for e.g)>> telegram bot send message "Great! Now you'll get your schedule of your group class

I wanted make as side things I would like to do the back buttons using FSM, but I haven't figured that out either :<

```
from io import StringIO
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, KeyboardButton
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

**'''Get Data'''**
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSNR-Gvp7MBcYQo0GM5nU3UC7DSIGMCwKq-eQGIY_alqORpe1pvZ00PI63wNuOyiJbZI_AP6nSeWWop/pubhtml'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

tmp = (pd.read_html(StringIO(page.text))[0].iloc[4:, 1:]
       .dropna(how="all").T.set_index(4).T)

s = tmp.columns.to_series()
tmp.columns = (s.str.cat(s.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1)
                         .astype(str), sep="-").where(s.duplicated(keep=False), s))

df = tmp.set_index(["Время-1", "Время-2"]).rename_axis(columns=None)

print(df.loc["ПОНЕДЕЛЬНИК", "ДПО-3-23"])


**''' Get Schedule bot '''**
bot = Bot(token="my_token")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# Creating an Inline keyboard to start
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
async def welcome(message: types.Message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

    button_comtehno = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Comtehno", callback_data='comtehno')
    keyboard.add(button_comtehno)

    await message.reply("Привет, я Schedule bot ! Я здесь чтобы дать тебе твое расписание пар :з\n"
                              "\nДля того чтобы начать - выбери УЗ: ", reply_markup=keyboard)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda query: query.data == 'comtehno')
# Handler for clicking on the "Comtehno" button
async def comtehno_handler(query: types.CallbackQuery):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button_set_schedule = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Установить расписание", callback_data='set_schedule')
    button_schedule = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Фото Расписания", callback_data='расписание')
    button_go_site = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Сайт с расписанием", url='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSNR-Gvp7MBcYQo0GM5nU3UC7DSIGMCwKq-eQGIY_alqORpe1pvZ00PI63wNuOyiJbZI_AP6nSeWWop/pubhtml')
    keyboard.row(button_schedule, button_go_site)
    keyboard.row(button_set_schedule)

    await bot.send_message(query.from_user.id, "Выберите раздел:", reply_markup=keyboard)
# Handler for clicking on the "расписание" button
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda query: query.data == 'расписание')
async def schedule_handler(query: types.CallbackQuery):
    with open("Screenshot_13.png", 'rb') as photo:
        await bot.send_photo(query.from_user.id, photo)
        await bot.send_message(query.from_user.id, "Вот фото расписания")

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda query: query.data == 'set_schedule')
async def set_schedule(query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.send_message(query.from_user.id, "Для того чтобы автоматически получать расписание каждое утро отправьте сообщение по шаблону: \n\n"
                                               "ДПО-3-23")

@dp.message_handler()
async def answer(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Чтобы использовать функционал напишите /start или /help")


executor.start_polling(dp)
```